Exclude from speaking URL
I'm using TYPO3 13.1.1.
My understanding is that we don't need additional extension like realurl to manage addresses; It's a very good improvement but for a specific folder I need the equivalent of the old Exclude from speaking URL option that existed in version 6.x
This is my tree:
Ppage 1 // -> mysite.com/page-1
Page 2 // -> mysite.com/page-2
|Folder 3
|---- Page 3 // -> mysite.com/folder-3/page-3

How to make the Page 3 URL like mysite.com/page-3, excluding the /folder-3/ part?

That was never a core feature, it was a realurl feature.
The TYPO3 speaking url implementation since TYPO3 v9 does not support that out of the box.
If you need that behaviour, you could extend the database schema and use the hook to modify the slug generation yourself - or you may have a look into the b13/masi [1] extension which implements these realurl features (and also have upgrade/import of old realurl settings in place.
Sadly, it has not yet v13 support - but may ask politly if they could at least add the constraint on the dev branch so you can test it out and report compatibility with v13.

[1] b13/masi


Ok, thank you. I'm going to look this extension then. I did downgrade my website to V12 because I need a lot of extensions which are not supporting v13. Unfortunately, the documentation of Masi is not very complete
